# Extracting single value from objects in the JSON array and writing to a range in Sheets

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script

Disclaimer: All names appearing are to my knowledge made up names and do not represent names of  of real individuals. Any such occurence is purely coincidental.

I am making a call to an external api and get results. See snippet of what the response looks like. I am however running a into a problem when trying to extract the name value from the attributes object within the array.

```
"included": [
        13 items
0: {
            5 items
"type": "Person"
"id": "96840658"
"attributes": {
                28 items
"accounting_administrator":False
"anniversary":NULL
"avatar": "https://avatars.planningcenteronline.com/uploads/initials/MS.png"
"birthdate":NULL
"can_create_forms":False
"child":False
"created_at": "2021-08-22T18:03:28Z"
"demographic_avatar_url": "https://avatars.planningcenteronline.com/uploads/initials/MS.png"
"directory_status": "no_access"
"first_name": "Kloogy"
"gender":NULL
"given_name":NULL
"grade":NULL
"graduation_year":NULL
"inactivated_at":NULL
"last_name": "Sexton"
"medical_notes":NULL
"membership":NULL
"middle_name":NULL
"name": "Kloogy Sexton"
"nickname":NULL
"passed_background_check":False
"people_permissions":NULL
"remote_id":NULL
"school_type":NULL
"site_administrator":False
"status": "active"
"updated_at": "2021-08-22T18:03:28Z"
            }
```

The array has 13 objects in the list. I am looping through the 13 objects to extract the name with the apps script code below and push it to an array called "candidates. I want the names as a list in a single array. However when I look at the log what I am getting looks like 13 arrays each one incremented with another name until all 13 names are output in the last array.

```
//Parse the JSON reply
var data = response.getContentText();
var results = JSON.parse(data);
var people = results['included'];
Logger.log(people)
var numberofpeople = results['data']['attributes']['total_people'];
Logger.log(numberofpeople)
var candidates = []
numRows = results['data']['attributes']['total_people']
//Logger.log(numRows)
for (var i = 0; i < numberofpeople; i++) {

candidates.push(i, 
   people[i]["attributes"]["name"],
)
Logger.log(candidates)

}
```

Sample of Log.

```
[0.0, Kloogy Sexton]
[0.0, Kloogy Sexton, 1.0, Valentine Dudley]
[0.0, Kloogy Sexton, 1.0, Valentine Dudley, 2.0, Jackson Underwoof]
[0.0, Kloogy Sexton, 1.0, Valentine Dudley, 2.0, Jackson Underwoof, 3.0, Akeem Smiley]
[0.0, Kloogy Sexton, 1.0, Valentine Dudley, 2.0, Jackson Underwoof, 3.0, Akeem Smiley, 4.0, Brianna Booleee]
```

Any tips on where I am going wrong in the loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this I love to use map:

```js
const candidateNames = results.included.map(person => person.attributes.name)
```

That being said, the reason you code doesn't work is because you are using `push(i, name)`. JavaScript `push` always adds at the back. It also support an arbitrary number of arguments to `push`, which get added at the end, in order. So the result is `[0, <name 0>, 1, <name 1>, ...]`.

### References

- [Array.prototype.push() (MDN's JavaScript reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Array.prototype.map() (MDN's JavaScript reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need this:

```
candidates.push([ i, people[i]["attributes"]["name"] ]);
```

Or this:

```
candidates.push(i + ", " + people[i]["attributes"]["name"]);
```

Or:

```
candidates.push(people[i]["attributes"]["name"]);
```

It depends on what exactly you mean by 'as a list in a single array'.

```js
var results = {"included": [
    { "id": "96840658", "attributes": { "name": "Kloogy Sexton" } },
    { "id": "96840659", "attributes": { "name": "John Smit" } },
    { "id": "96840660", "attributes": { "name": "Nobody" } },
]};

var people = results['included'];
var numberofpeople = people.length;

var candidates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberofpeople; i++) {
    candidates.push([i, people[i]["attributes"]["name"] ] );
}
console.log(candidates)

var candidates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberofpeople; i++) {
    candidates.push(i + ", " + people[i]["attributes"]["name"] );
}
console.log(candidates)

var candidates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberofpeople; i++) {
    candidates.push(people[i]["attributes"]["name"]);
}
console.log(candidates)
```

Comment: Hi @Yuri What I mean is the current I am getting this multiple arrays as I showed in my example of the log data. I only want lsit like this with all the names:  [ Kloogy Sexton,  Valentine Dudley,  Jackson Underwoof,  Akeem Smiley,  Brianna Booleee]

Comment: Then you don't need `i`. Use this: `candidates.push(people[i]["attributes"]["name"] );`

Comment: I've added the third options to my answer.

Comment: And, just in case, I'd propose you to try to put the `console.log(candidates)` outside of the loop (put it after of the loop) . It's not error, but If you're confused this 'looped' output?

Comment: moving the console.log(candidates) outside the loop worked. I think that is what was causing the issue! I was probably seeing each step in the loop being output to the log instead of the final output. Now to figure out, how to write each name to a range in the Google Sheet.